# Insert each word from a string on a seperate row in MySql

Tags: mysql, string, insert

In MySql, Let's say I have a table

```
myTable
  ID
  word
```

I would like to insert a string into the table, but have each word from the string insert on a seperate row.

For example, if I have a string...

"The quick brown fox jumped"

...it would be inserted like so:

```
myTable
  1 - The
  2 - quick
  3 - brown
  4 - fox
  5 - jumped
```

I am wondering if it is possible to write an sql query that can do this, given the string?  Or do I have to parse up the string beforehand?

Thanks (in advance) for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to work some odd magic using `SUBSTRING INDEX()` but I don't think it would be pretty. In addition, it would require you to know the indices prior to the `Insert`. I would recommend parsing prior to the insert. Check the [MySQL 5.0 Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) specific to `String` functions.